# Why doesn't an absolutely positioned element position itself relative to its parent if the parent is static?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I've heard that an absolutely positioned element positions itself relative to its first non-statically-positioned ancestor. But is there some more holistic reason for this? Or is it just an arbitrary choice that was made, that it wouldn't be true for static elements.

I guess I'm wondering if there's some unified theory of CSS, so to speak, i.e. one that's perhaps complicated, but less complex. One which outlines the behavior of position and static and absolute in such a way that this interaction comes out of it as a natural consequence.

I also can't find an explicit reference to this rule in the CSS spec; that might help.

Comment: `static` is the _default_ position of any given element, unless you specify otherwise. And if absolute positioning would take that as a reference point, then you would not be able to position an element absolutely in reference to anything but its parent element …

Comment: @CBroe Please make your comments as an answer. Short, insightful and concise. This should be an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: FWIW, In the CSS 2.1 spec, Section [9.3.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#choose-position) under "absolute" says "These properties specify offsets with respect to the box's containing block" and section [9.8.4](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#comp-abspos) says "The containing block for a positioned box is established by the nearest positioned ancestor (or, if none exists, the initial containing block)". Which doesn't explain why like CBroe's answer does.

Comment: @Alohci Thanks for pointing that out. When I read it initially I didn't see their definition of containing block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply because forcing people to position their elements relative to the parent element is a needless limitation. What if I want to position an element relative to `<body>`? What if I want to position an element relative to a specific ancestor? Well, I could just set `position: relative` on the target parent. Without this, I'd need to use JS.

Of course, I don't think this is the *best* way it could be implemented. If I wrote the spec my self, I'd make it:

```
position: absolute(selector);
```

But of course, I don't write the spec.

Answer (score 3):

`static` is the default position of any given element, unless you specify otherwise. And if absolute positioning would take that as a reference point, then you would not be able to position an element absolutely in reference to *anything but* its parent element.

Therefor, it was specified that absolute positioning takes the nearest ancestor element with a position *other* than `static` as reference point (or the viewport itself if there is none).